# How to delete just one key from a python dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I am creating a dictionary, that potentially has keys that are the same, but the values of each key are different.  Here is the example dict:

```
y = {44:0, 55.4:1, 44:2, 5656:3}
del y[44]
print y
{5656: 3, 55.399999999999999: 1}
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
 del y[44:0]
```

Or something of that nature.

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? do you need to store multiple values for a key? dictionary keys are unique assining keys will overwrite

Comment: Thanks.  I'll have to figure out a way to make custom keys instead of auto generating them.

Comment: I was trying to store positions in space as keys, so when I sort a list, I can quickly use the value to find the proper index in an unsorted list

Answer (score 4):

You never had duplicate keys:

```
>>> y = {44:0, 55.4:1, 44:2, 5656:3}
>>> y
{5656: 3, 55.4: 1, 44: 2}
```

A dictionary can be initialised with duplicate keys, but all but one will be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

Just an idea- instead of having scalar values, why not a collection of some kind? Perhaps even a set if they are unique values:

```
myDict = {44:set([1, 2, 3])}
```

So to add or remove an object:

```
myDict[44].add(1)
myDict[44].remove(1)
```

For adding a new key:

```
if newKey not in myDict:
    myDict[newKey] = set() # new empty set
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is moot.  In your `y` declaration, the `44:2` wouldn't go alongside `44:0`, it would overwrite it.  You'd need to use a different key if you want both values in the dictionary.

Answer (score -1):

Before deleting:--

```
>>>dic={"a":"A","b":"B","c":"C","d":"D","e":"E"}

>>> del dic['a']
```

after deleting :-

```
>>>dic
{'b': 'B','c': 'C','d': 'D','e': 'E'}
```